# webapp is not generated with maven application jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, mvn-repo

I am stuck in the middle of 1 issue. I have a maven project the structure looks something like this below.

```
- DockerFile
- pom.xml
- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/main/webapp
```

Whenever I try to build my docker image locally with the script `mvn -Pdocker package`. The target folder is generated having my application.jar file. But if I extract this file the webapp is not in it. What am I doing wrong here?
My DockerFile looks like this

```
FROM xxxxx.dkr.ecr.some-region.some-cloud.com/s24-base-jdk11 as builder
WORKDIR application
COPY target/application.jar ./
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./

EXPOSE xxxx

USER nobody
```

Comment: Does the extraction actually work? What `java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract` does is it runs your application, giving extract as argument.

Comment: @kutschkem Yes it does work. Locally I checked it and can see folders that are mentioned in the DockerFile above. The only issue is it does not extract anything from webapp folder. Rest of the folders I can see them after extracting.

Comment: I do not understand why you need `COPY --from=builder ...` at all - you do not have a second stage in your Dockerfile.